Jenkins Build queue slows down Jenkins Master UI
What I've noticed is the Jenkins master starts lagging if the Build queue is 200+ jobs, Even though the Jenkins VM has like 8CPU 24GB ram. I expect things to be much smoother, how can I improve this? When I notice it's lagging, I check the Resource usage with 'btop' I only see 1 core on 100% most of the time and rest are below 15% usage
So

No jobs run on Jenkins master, master has 0 executors, we have alot of agents.

Garbage collection works great Jenkins uses 80% of system memory, using "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4”

throttling jobs is not an option

Plugins Already optimized and latest, latest LTS Jenkins too.

We have a test Jenkins with same VM specs, but no agents connected to it and no jobs running so there is basically no load on it, and even that starts lagging after Build queue goes 200/300+ and once it’s 1000+ it’s very very slow. So based on this, I am quite sure the lag is due to the Build queue length.


Thanks in Advance.

It sounds like it's the UI - your browser, that's lagging, not the Jenkins server.
